# Cannot find the Silverlight Business Applications project type

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

This is what I have:

[image]

And my book! says pick `Business Application` as the type. But I don't see it.
What things should I install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using visual studio 2013 this template type has been removed.

> From Msdn:
>
> WCF Rich Internet Application Services item templates and project templates (for example, Silverlight Business Application template) are removed for Visual Studio 2013. If you open an existing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or Visual Studio 2012 project containing WCF Rich Internet Application services items, you can build, and maintain the project using Visual Studio 2013. New WCF Rich Internet Application Services projects and additive changes are discouraged because the project and item templates have been removed.

You can find more infomation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161050.aspx)